# How to regex German street addresses with numbers (infix)

Tags: regex

I've got these two addresses:

```
Straße des 17 Juni 122a
Str. 545 3
```

See https://regex101.com/r/2WT48R/5

I need to filter for the street and number.

My desired output would be:

```
streets = [Straße des, Str. ]
numbers = [17 Juni 122a, 545 3]
```

This is my regex:

```
(?<street>[\S ]+?)\s*(?<number>\d+[\w\s\/-]*)$
```

Output should look like:

```
streets = [Straße des 17 Juni, Str. 545]
numbers = [122a, 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one answer by myself:

`(?<street>[\S ]+?)\s*(?<number>\d+\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*([-\/]\s*\d*\s*\w?\s*)*)$`

The [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WT48R/6) includes several additional test cases.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Looks like there's no spaces in the "numbers" part of your regex - you can use that to cut away those extra characters getting stuck in your second capture group.</s>

`(?<street>[\S ]+)\s(?<number>\d+\S*$)`

By allowing no whitespace in the second capture group, it won't match the numbers `17` or `545` too early.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eBU8r9/1/)

EDIT: after seeing your more detailed list of examples on [your own demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WT48R/6), the following regex will match the complete set of your test cases:

`(?<street>[\S \t]+?) ?(?<number>[\d\s]+[\w-\/]*?$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eBU8r9/3/)

Comment: Hey @NickReed thank you. I think your solution processes all correctly but the 4th line. `Straße des 17 Juni 122a` and `Straße des 17. Juni 122a` should look like street: "Straße des 17 Juni" or "Straße des 17. Juni" and number: 122a

Comment: Regex updated. I've also updated your self-answer - if your own answer solves your problem, please remember to accept it!